# How to obtain Pmenu result as a list variable in VIM?

Tags: vim

I want to get the Pmenu result and store them into a list variable

for example:

there are two words in the Pmenu
aAA
aBB

> aAA
>
> aBB

can i write something like "`let list=SOMEFUNCTION()`"

to make `list == ['aAA','aBB']`

actually, I could obtain these words by functions in neocomplcache plugin

but i want to know how to get them without plugin functions

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any built-in Vim function that gives you access to the built-in completions (like `<C-N>`). When you write your own (`:help complete-functions`), you'll have that list of matches and can store it / pass it around (and I think this is what the *neocomplcache* plugin does).

So, you have to re-implement the built-in completions, or use a plugin's functionality. Speaking of plugins, with my [CompleteHelper plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3914), you can easily get that list:

```
:let base = 'foo'
:let matches = []
:call CompleteHelper#FindMatches(matches, '\V\<' . escape(base, '\') . '\k\+', {'complete': '.,w.b'})
```